# Displaying a array using showMessageDialog and return selected value

Tags: java, arrays, swing, joptionpane

I want to show my array (marked) on click event of `btnCurrentStatus`, and then I want to return the selected value from user. The code I am using for that is as below but here by `showMessageDialog` method I can only manage to display the array, what I want is that user can select one of the values, and I want to return that index.

How to achieve that?

```
btnCurrentStatus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int j = 0;
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < total_question; i++) {
            if (question_status[i] == 1) {
                marked[j] = i + 1;
                j++;
            //  System.out.println((i + 1) + " : Marked");
            } else if (question_status[i] == 2) {
                locked[k] = i + 1;
                c++;
                //System.out.println((i + 1) + " : Locked");
            }
        }
        String display = "";
        // String markedq []= new String[] {"1","2","3","4"};
        for (int a = 0; a < marked.length; a++) {
            if (marked[a] != 0) {
                display += marked[a] + "\n";
            }
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, display);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...) if you want to get a selection from the user. Instead use a different dialog, such as JOptionPane.showInputDialog:

```
 // from the JOptionPane API
 Object[] possibleValues = { "First", "Second", "Third" };

 Object selectedValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
             "Choose one", "Input",
             JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null,
             possibleValues, possibleValues[0]);
```